# Problem using MQTT: published message will publish but won't receive

Tags: gpio, python, mqtt

I wrote this code for controlling gpio pins

everything is ok but i cant turn on or off gpio pins

message will publish but it will not turn on or off gpio pins

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# True is off
# False is on
# WTF

P1 = 17
P2 = 4
P3 = 3
P4 = 2
P5 = 27
P6 = 15
P7 = 18
P8 = 14

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(P1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(P2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(P3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(P4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(P5, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(P6, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(P7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(P8, GPIO.OUT)
time.sleep(0.4)
GPIO.output(P1, True)
GPIO.output(P2, True)
GPIO.output(P3, True)
GPIO.output(P4, True)
GPIO.output(P5, True)
GPIO.output(P6, True)
GPIO.output(P7, True)
GPIO.output(P8, True)


# pins = {"P1": 17, "P2": 4, "P3": 3, "P4": 2, "P5": 27, "P6": 15, "P7": 18, "P8": 14}
# pins = {1: 17, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 27, 6: 15, 7: 18, 8: 14}
# for i in pins.items():
#     GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)
#     GPIO.output(i, True)

def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("Payload Published: " + str(mid))


def on_connect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("Connecting...")
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected!!!\nResult code: " + str(rc))
        # Subscribing
        client.subscribe("Lights/LED1")
    elif rc == 5:
        print("Auth error!\nReturn code: " + str(rc))


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Message Received.")
    print("topic: " + str(msg.topic))
    print("Payload" + str(msg.payload))
    print("QOS" + str(msg.retain))

    if msg.payload == "exit(0)":
        client.disconnect()
        print("exit with code 0")

    # True is off
    # False is on
    if msg.topic == "Lights/LED1":
        if msg.payload == "0":
            GPIO.output(P1, True)
        if msg.payload == "1":
            GPIO.output(P1, False)
    # if msg.payload.decode() == "exit(0)":
    # client.disconnect()


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("disconnecting...")
    client.loop_stop()


def on_log(topic, userdata, level, buf):
    print("Logs:" + str(buf))


def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid))


def on_unsubscribed(client, userdata, mid):
    print("Unsubscribed: " + str(mid))


# instance of Client class
client = mqtt.Client()
# Callbacks
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
client.on_unsubscribe = on_unsubscribed

host = "raspberrypi"
port = 1883
keep_alive = 60

client.connect(host, port, keep_alive)
time.sleep(2)

client.loop_start()

while True:
    print("type 1")
    # time.sleep(1)
    client.publish("Lights/LED1", input())
    print("type 0")
    # time.sleep(1)
    # topic, message, qos
    client.publish("Lights/LED1", input())
```

I think it must print the code written in on_connect() but it doesn't print them

and also i can see the message published from MQTT-Dash android app

Comment: if nothing prints in `on_connect`, perhaps `rc` is something OTHER than 0 or 5 - try printing what `rc` is - also, you're publishing to MQTT ... but you never subscribe to any topics, so, even IF you managed to connect, you'd never get any messages

Comment: I tried to print `rc` in `on_connect` but it didn't print anything.

Comment: Update: I managed to fix this by putting `client.subscribe("Lights/LED1")` after `client.connect()`. But i don't know why `on_connect()` function never called.

Comment: `everything is ok but i cant turn on or off gpio pins` ... why are you even talking about the GPIO pins ... the problem is that you are not receiving any messages .... it is like saying `i can't race my automobile` when the problem is that the engine does not work